# How can I open some system setting pages in iOS11?

Tags: url, reverse-engineering, application-settings, ios11, setting

iOS11 is now a beta version. How can I jump to sysetm setting sub pages?

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
```

URL such as `Prefs:root=WIFI` or `App-Prefs:root=WIFI`, does not work at all.
Does anyone have a solution ?

Thanks very much.

Comment: This is the only way I'm aware of. File a bug report explaining the existing URLs are not working at bugreport.apple.com.